# Onclick event time gap

Tags: javascript

below is my code

```
<div class="play" onclick="updateData()" title="xyz" id="pqr"></div>
```

Problem is that when I click on update data multiple times, then events are queued which leads to abnormal behavior.

How can I disable the mouse click on this div for some time interval?

**My purpose is to prevent the user from clicking it multiple times uncessarily**

Comment: `onclick="updateData();this.onclick=null;"`

Comment: will this permanaently disable the onclick event?

Comment: I want to disable click event for ..Lets say 500 milli second...

Comment: you may add var updateDataFlag = true; function updateData(){ if(!updateDataFlag)return; updateDataFlag = false; ... ; updateDataFlag = true }

Answer (score 0):

You can use an utility like Lodash's [_.debounce()](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce):

```
var buttonListener = function() {
  // This function will be called only if 500ms are passed since the last click
  updateData();
}
var intervalButton = _.debounce(buttonListener, 500);
$('#pqr').on('click', intervalButton);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LaQnb/6/

Answer (score 0):

Update your trigger element function call to include `this`:

```
<div class="play" onclick="updateData(this)" title="xyz" id="pqr"></div>
```

Update your function:

```
function updateData(triggerElement) {

    // disable further clicks until we re-bind the event...
    triggerElement.onclick = null;

    // rebind the event after 500ms
    setTimeout(function() {
        triggerElement.onclick = updateData;
    }, 500);


    // ... rest of your function's code ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="play" onclick="updateData(); this.onclick='javascript:void(0);'" title="xyz" id="pqr"></div>
```

it replace your onclick event.

Comment: This does not address the fact that a user will need to be able to trigger the click event again after a specified delay has elapsed.